# Dockerized webdriver testing for Microsoft Edge

Tags: selenium, docker, microsoft-edge

I'm helping set up web testing frameworks for a team that runs web tests on a project that already supports Firefox and Chrome. They want to extend it to be able to test Microsoft Edge.

So far we've been using Selenium grid with Docker and Jenkins but only for Firefox and Chrome.

Is there a way to extend a set up like this for Microsoft Edge? Or is there a way to dockerize Micrsoft Edge testing?

I know there is a webdriver for Edge compatible with selenium grid but I've seen nothing about how to dockerize it.

I want to use Docker because it keeps all the Jenkins slaves clean and allows for controlled versions of browsers, and we can control multiple containers with Docker-Compose.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use WebDriver with Windows Insider to test web projects with MS Edge.

WebDriver is an emerging standard through which Web developers can write tests to automate Web browsers for site testing. It provides a programmable remote control for developing complex user scenarios and running them in an automated fashion against your website in a browser.

Reference:

[Bringing automated testing to Microsoft Edge through WebDriver](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/23/bringing-automated-testing-to-microsoft-edge-through-webdriver/#XTY3QkgOMpQ4UQX2.97)

Other useful links:

[Automated browser testing on Microsoft Edge, Firefox and Chrome for free.](https://oliverlundquist.com/2017/09/25/automated-browser-testing-on-windows-for-free.html)

[Free Testing on Microsoft Edge](https://www.browserstack.com/test-on-microsoft-edge-browser#live-cloud)